# "Muting" first point in time animation of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, animation, timeslider

I am trying to produce a time-lapse map of points. The problem is, after enabling time, the earliest point in the layer appears before beginning the animation.  In other words, its just on the map by itself.

How can I get the first point to appear only *after* the animation starts, ie after I click play on the time slider?

I am using ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a time-enabled layer handy so I haven't tested this and can't say for sure it will work, but you could create a feature in your point layer with null geometry (edit the point layer, open its attribute table, and create a new record at the end of it) and assign it a time earlier than your earliest actual point. The animation should start with that new feature, but with no geometry, it won't show up on your map.